# Error when using preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a original code like this

```
$text = preg_replace("#\[tex\](.*?)\[/tex\]#sie","'<img src=\'http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\1\' border=\'0\' align=\'absmiddle\' alt=\'\\1\'></img>'", $text);
```

And I want to change it with `preg_replace_callback`. I guess it should be like this

```
$text = preg_replace_callback("#\[latex\](.*?)\[/latex\]#si",
      function($m){ return "<img src=\'http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?".$m[1]."\' border=\'0\' align=\'absmiddle\' alt=\'".$m[1]."\'></img>";},
$text);
```

But it doesn't work! Please help me!

Comment: Both code samples work pretty much identically for me. In the first example your regex searches for `[tex]` whereas in the second example it is `[latex]`. Is this correct? You are also unnecessarily (I think) quoting single quotes inside a double-quoted string, so I think you can remove the backslashes on (eg) `src=\'`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually there is no need for a callback. Just drop the `e` and reformat replacement: [`$text = preg_replace("#\[tex\](.*?)\[/tex\]#si", "<img src='http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$1' border='0' align='absmiddle' alt='$1'></img>", $text);`](https://eval.in/534610) Btw closing `</img>` [for what that?](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/html-void-elements.htm) Further would prefer double quotes : )